# Why does appending to the body in this way break Javascript on a page?

Tags: javascript

I know it's not right to append to the body in this way, but why does this break Javascript on a page?

```
document.body.innerHTML += 1;
```

This is a very simple example of a way to recreate a problem that we've just been debugging. Whilst syntactically it's ok, I don't understand why it seems to break Javascript on a page.

If you run the above code on a page in your console then try clicking on something on the page that uses Javascript, it stops working.

Comment: Because it recreates the whole tree, removing all added event handlers

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ok, that makes sense to me. Want to add it as an answer so that it can be accepted?